# alert when jQuery fails to get the ip address.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip

I am new to javascript and jQuery. 
I want trying to get the ip when the page loads.

I am using this code to get and alert IP:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
            $myip = response.ip;
            alert($myip);
        }, "jsonp");
```

This pop out IP only if the internet if connected. I want to show a pop-message "Connection problem" if it fails to get ip. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look: [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    $myip = response.ip;
    alert($myip);
    }, "jsonp")
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Besides, the `jqhrx` object exposes the following to make it easy to get the call status any time later:

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will expose the following properties and methods:
>
> readyState
>
> status
>
> statusText
>
> statusCode()

Comment: @Venky That's why we need the `.fail` handler.

Comment: @Venky No, `'fail` callback is not "called from the server" as you say. It is a generic failure notification mech.

Comment: The backword compatibility thing went overhead, quite a novice in web dev. But thanks for the detailed answer.